Custom VerbatimEnvironment with two optional arguments
Currently I use a custom VerbatimEnvironment with an embodied tcolorbox and one optional argument for the title of the box. This works great in general, e.g.:
\begin{mybox}[Example]{console}
Hello \highlight{world}
Foo Bar
\end{mybox}

produces:

However I would like to use a second optional argument by which I can control the font size, e.g. like so:
\begin{mybox}[Example][\small]{console}
Hello \highlight{world}
Foo Bar
\end{mybox}

The order of the arguments does not matter. Maybe there are even other solutions by which the font size can be controlled dynamically.
This is a MWE:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkgray}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{lightgray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.08}

%%% Using guillemets (« ») as German quotation marks
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}  % Activates " as quotation marks for outer quotes

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% This defines a custom "mybox" environment
%%% The optional (first) argument can be used for a title of the box
%%% The second argument specifies the type to draw an appropriate symbol
%%% file: draws a file system symbol
%%% console: draws a console symbol
% \begin{mybox}[optional title]{console}
% Smallest element: 2
% \end{mybox}

\usepackage{fontawesome}  % For the use of symbols
\usepackage{etoolbox}     % For advanced macro programming, e.g. \ifstrequal
\usepackage{fancyvrb}     % For an advanced verbatim environment
\usepackage{tcolorbox}    % For creating colored boxes
\tcbuselibrary{breakable} % Allows content in tcolorbox environments to continue across page breaks

%%% Enables conditional statements in LaTeX
\usepackage{ifthen}

%%% The \highlight{} command can be used within a mybox 
%%% to print specific parts in bold
\newcommand\highlight[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\newenvironment{mybox}[2][]{
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    breakable,          % Allow page breaks
    colback=lightgray,
    coltitle=white,
    colbacktitle=darkgray,
    colframe=darkgray,
    boxrule=0.9pt,      % Thickness of the box frame
    boxsep=5pt,         % Distance between the box content and its frame
    arc=1pt,            % Corner radius of the box
    fonttitle=\sffamily,
    toptitle=0mm,       % Distance from the top of the title area to the title line
    bottomtitle=0mm,    % Distance from the bottom of the title area to the title line
    left=3pt,           % Distance of the box content from the left inner edge of the box
    right=3pt,          % Distance of the box content from the right inner edge of the box
    before upper={\begin{BVerbatim}}, % Inserts BVerbatim at the beginning
    after upper={\end{BVerbatim}},    % Inserts BVerbatim at the end
    before upper={\DisableQuotes},    % Disables guillemets inside the box and considers line breaks
    after upper={\EnableQuotes},      % Restores guillemets after the box
    title={%
      \ifstrequal{#2}{file}{\faFileTextO\hspace{5mm}}{%
        \ifstrequal{#2}{console}{\faTerminal\hspace{5mm}}{}%
      }#1
    },
  ]
  \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]%
    }{
  \end{Verbatim}
  \end{tcolorbox}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}[Example]{console}
Hello \highlight{world}
Foo Bar
\end{mybox}

%%% This would be great to have:
% \begin{mybox}[Example][\small]{console}
% Hello \highlight{world}
% Foo Bar
% \end{mybox}

\end{document}

Do you have any idea on how to accomplish this task?

You can use \NewDocumentEnvironment instead of \newenvironment. It allows you to flexibly define the position of optional arguments (and multiple such arguments). O{} means an optional argument defaulting to an empty value, m means a mandatory argument.
However note that with this approach you always have to specify the first optional argument to set the second. Maybe a key=value approach would be better here. Be it as it may, here's your code:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkgray}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{lightgray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.08}

%%% Using guillemets (« ») as German quotation marks
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}  % Activates " as quotation marks for outer quotes

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% This defines a custom "mybox" environment
%%% The optional (first) argument can be used for a title of the box
%%% The second argument specifies the type to draw an appropriate symbol
%%% file: draws a file system symbol
%%% console: draws a console symbol
% \begin{mybox}[optional title]{console}
% Smallest element: 2
% \end{mybox}

\usepackage{fontawesome}  % For the use of symbols
\usepackage{etoolbox}     % For advanced macro programming, e.g. \ifstrequal
\usepackage{fancyvrb}     % For an advanced verbatim environment
\usepackage{tcolorbox}    % For creating colored boxes
\tcbuselibrary{breakable} % Allows content in tcolorbox environments to continue across page breaks

%%% Enables conditional statements in LaTeX
\usepackage{ifthen}

%%% The \highlight{} command can be used within a mybox 
%%% to print specific parts in bold
\newcommand\highlight[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mybox}{O{} O{} m}{
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    breakable,          % Allow page breaks
    colback=lightgray,
    coltitle=white,
    colbacktitle=darkgray,
    colframe=darkgray,
    boxrule=0.9pt,      % Thickness of the box frame
    boxsep=5pt,         % Distance between the box content and its frame
    arc=1pt,            % Corner radius of the box
    fonttitle=\sffamily,
    toptitle=0mm,       % Distance from the top of the title area to the title line
    bottomtitle=0mm,    % Distance from the bottom of the title area to the title line
    left=3pt,           % Distance of the box content from the left inner edge of the box
    right=3pt,          % Distance of the box content from the right inner edge of the box
    before upper={\begin{BVerbatim}}, % Inserts BVerbatim at the beginning
    after upper={\end{BVerbatim}},    % Inserts BVerbatim at the end
    before upper={\DisableQuotes},    % Disables guillemets inside the box and considers line breaks
    after upper={\EnableQuotes},      % Restores guillemets after the box
    title={%
      \ifstrequal{#3}{file}{\faFileTextO\hspace{5mm}}{%
        \ifstrequal{#3}{console}{\faTerminal\hspace{5mm}}{}%
      }#1
    },
  ]%
  #2%
  \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]%
    }{%
  \end{Verbatim}
  \end{tcolorbox}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}[Example]{console}
Hello \highlight{world}
Foo Bar
\end{mybox}

%%% This would be great to have:
\begin{mybox}[Example][\small]{console}
Hello \highlight{world}
Foo Bar
\end{mybox}

\end{document}


Since you said you wanted to see/figure out how key=value would look like. The following turns your optional argument into a key=value argument instead of adding a second argument. It also uses \NewDocumentEnvironment and its ={<key>} syntax. This turns your optional argument into the value for <key> if parsing says it's not a key=value argument. This allows you to use a short syntax if you only need to declare the title, but also gives you the versatility of key=value.
For the key=value parsing I use expkv-def here (disclaimer: since that's my package), the same (with a bit of different looking code/syntax) is also possible with just the LaTeX kernel, or some other key=value package. If you're interested in the kernel solution I can provide that as well.
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkgray}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{lightgray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.08}

%%% Using guillemets (« ») as German quotation marks
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}  % Activates " as quotation marks for outer quotes

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% This defines a custom "mybox" environment
%%% The optional (first) argument can be used for a title of the box
%%% The second argument specifies the type to draw an appropriate symbol
%%% file: draws a file system symbol
%%% console: draws a console symbol
% \begin{mybox}[optional title]{console}
% Smallest element: 2
% \end{mybox}

\usepackage{fontawesome}  % For the use of symbols
\usepackage{fancyvrb}     % For an advanced verbatim environment
\usepackage{tcolorbox}    % For creating colored boxes
\tcbuselibrary{breakable} % Allows content in tcolorbox environments to continue across page breaks

%%% The \highlight{} command can be used within a mybox 
%%% to print specific parts in bold
\newcommand\highlight[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\usepackage{expkv-def}
\ekvdefinekeys{mybox}
  {
     store title = \myboxTitle
    ,store font = \myboxFont
  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mybox}{={title}O{} m}{
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \ekvset{mybox}{#1}%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    breakable,          % Allow page breaks
    colback=lightgray,
    coltitle=white,
    colbacktitle=darkgray,
    colframe=darkgray,
    boxrule=0.9pt,      % Thickness of the box frame
    boxsep=5pt,         % Distance between the box content and its frame
    arc=1pt,            % Corner radius of the box
    fonttitle=\sffamily,
    toptitle=0mm,       % Distance from the top of the title area to the title line
    bottomtitle=0mm,    % Distance from the bottom of the title area to the title line
    left=3pt,           % Distance of the box content from the left inner edge of the box
    right=3pt,          % Distance of the box content from the right inner edge of the box
    before upper={\begin{BVerbatim}}, % Inserts BVerbatim at the beginning
    after upper={\end{BVerbatim}},    % Inserts BVerbatim at the end
    before upper={\DisableQuotes},    % Disables guillemets inside the box and considers line breaks
    after upper={\EnableQuotes},      % Restores guillemets after the box
    title={%
      \ifstrequal{#2}{file}{\faFileTextO\hspace{5mm}}{%
        \ifstrequal{#2}{console}{\faTerminal\hspace{5mm}}{}%
      }\myboxTitle
    },
  ]%
  \myboxFont
  \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]%
    }{%
  \end{Verbatim}
  \end{tcolorbox}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}[Example]{console}
Hello \highlight{world}
Foo Bar
\end{mybox}

%%% This would be great to have:
\begin{mybox}[title=Example, font=\small]{console}
Hello \highlight{world}
Foo Bar
\end{mybox}

\end{document}


Output of both code variants:


Thanks a lot, this is already absolutely sufficient, even though I may want to figure out how a key-value solution may look like :-)

@taocp I added a key=value version of your environment.

Wow, this is absolutely incredible. Thank you so much, I really like this clean solution.
